# MySQL convert height format from centimeters to feet-inches?

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

Format in my DB is: in centimeters like 137 cm

i want to convert example like **137 cm to  4'6" (4 feet, 6 inches)**

Actual Table: height in centimeters

eg:

```
SELECT * FROM height

id height_cm
1  137
2  139
3  172
4  175
```

I expect the following result as feet-inches when I do SQL query

```
id height_finc
1  4'6"
2  4'7"
3  5'8"
4  5'9"
```

formula is : `1 inch = 2.54 cm` and `1 foot = 12 inches`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do some arithmetic operation for this while doing the select.

Lets start getting the `inch` and `foot`

```
mysql> select id, 
floor(height_cm/(12*2.54)) as foot , 
round((height_cm mod (12*2.54))/2.54) as inch from height ;
+------+------+------+
| id   | foot | inch |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    4 |    6 |
|    2 |    4 |    7 |
|    3 |    5 |    8 |
|    4 |    5 |    9 |
+------+------+------+
```

Now using `concat` we can format the display

```
mysql> select id, 
concat(
 floor(height_cm/(12*2.54))
 ,'\''
 ,round((height_cm mod (12*2.54))/2.54)
 ,'"'
) as height_finc from height ;
+------+-------------+
| id   | height_finc |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | 4'6"        |
|    2 | 4'7"        |
|    3 | 5'8"        |
|    4 | 5'9"        |
+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Great thanks for your help , it solved my problem. i also want to know that, query level calculation is best or i should calculate cm to F-inch using loop after fetching records from database.

Comment: Well simple arithmetic operation does not make much load on DB. So its not a bad idea to have it done on DB level.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically arithmetic and string formatting:

```
select floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)) as feet,
       (height_cm - floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)) * 12 * 2.54) / 2.54 as inches
```

To format as a string:

```
select concat(floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)), '''', 
              round((height_cm - floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)) * 12 * 2.54) / 2.54), '"') as feet_inches
```

I think this is simpler as:

```
select concat(floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)), '''', 
              round(height_cm / 2.54) % 12, '"')
```

Comment: thanks , i used this : dbQuery('select concat(floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)), '''', 
              round(height_cm / 2.54) % 12, '"')'); but its giving me  single quotes error ?